# How to measure similarity between code snippets written in programming language

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, similarity

I am trying to solve the following problem.
Given a particular code snippet I need to give back the top review comments for the code snippet, here we want to give all the comments that were given to similar code snippets.

I am trying to form it as a machine learning problem.I think we can use KNN algorithm, but here I am not sure how should I measure the similarity between two code snippet ? Is there any pre-existing similarity measure for it ? I tried to search in google but not found any useful link

Kindly help

Comment: Have you tried the [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) or the [nmslib](https://github.com/searchivarius/nmslib) library?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit distance** between the two strings containing the considered comments could be a useful measure of similarity.

Also, n-gram **cosine distance** could be useful, that is, you extract the n-grams (e.g. 3-char-segments), build the vectors counting these n-grams and calculate cosine distance.

Another one would be **Jaccard similarity** between n-gram vectors (as above).